# Equations involving particular values of the Dedekind psi function and powers of the kernel function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, asymptotics, divisibility, analytic-number-theory, prime-factorization

In this post we denote the Dedekind psi function as $\psi(m)$ for integers $m\geq 1$. As reference I add the Wikipedia [*Dedekind psi function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_psi_function), and [1]. One has the definition $\psi(1)=1$, and that the Dedekind psi function can be represented for a positive integer $m>1$ as $$\psi(m)=m\prod_{\substack{p\mid m\\p\text{ prime}}}\left(1+\frac{1}{p}\right).$$
On the other hand we denote the product of distinct primes dividing an integer $m>1$ as $\operatorname{rad}(m)$ see the Wikipedia [*Radical of an integer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_integer) thus $$\operatorname{rad}(m)=\prod_{\substack{p\mid m\\p\text{ prime}}}p$$
that takes the value $1$ for $m=1$. Both functions are multiplicative.

I was inspired in [1] and [2] to state the following questions.

> **Question 1.** I would like to know what work can be done about if the following equation (that is just an example of equation, look at next question) 
>   $$\psi(n)=\operatorname{rad}(n)^4\tag{1}$$
>   have finitely many solutions, when $n$ runs over positive integers greater or equal than $1$. **Many thanks.**

As clarification in previous RHS the expression is a fourth power. As example $$\psi(648)=\psi(2^3\cdot 3^4)=2^3\cdot\frac{3}{2}\cdot3^4\cdot\frac{4}{3}=6^4,$$ and the solutions that I know are listed here $1,648,337500,8696754$.

I don't know how to approach the problem that I think that it is similar than a problem that was in the literature ([1]). I emphasize that I'm asking for what work or heuristics can be done to know if previous equation admits finitely many solutions (after some helpful answer I should to accept the answer).

> **Question 2.** Let $k\geq 2$ be an integer, and for each fixed $k$ we consider the solutions $n\geq 1$ of the equation $$\psi(n)=(\operatorname{rad}(n))^k\tag{2}$$
>   (I've added the brackets just as a redundacy). Let $$N_k=\#\{n\geq 1:n\text{ solves }\psi(n)=\operatorname{rad}(n)^k\}.$$ I would like to know if it is possible to estimate roughly the size of $N_k$ in terms of $k$ or to get, roughly, some inequality involving some bound as below $$\text{a bound in terms of }k<N_k<\text{a bound in terms of }k.$$
>   **Many thanks.**

I'm not asking for a professional statement for the estimation of $N_k$, for $k\geq 2$, just some idea about the size of $N_k$ or some inequality deduced from some mathemaical reasonings or heuristics. For this question I was inspired in **Theorem** from [2].

### References:

[1] J. M. De Koninck, *Proposed problem* 10966, American Mathematical Monthly, **109** (2002), p. 759.

[2] J. M. De Koninck, F. Luca, and A. Sankaranarayanan, *Positive Integers Whose Euler Function Is a Power of Their Kernel Function*, Rocky Mountain J. Math. Vol. 36, No. 1 (2006), pp. 81-96.

[3] Tom M. Apostol, *Introduction to analytic number theory*, Undergraduate Texts in Mathematics, New York-Heidelberg: Springer-Verlag (1976).

Comment: I can to see the article [2] from Project EUCLID. I emphasize that I'm interested to study the size of $N_k$ with $k\geq 2$, just roughly to get an idea of what is the size of $N_k$ or the inequalities that these quantities $N_k$ satisfy, roughly in terms of $k$.

Comment: The clarification of previous comment, is that I'm not asking this post waiting answers at research level since I've asked two questions, and could be difficult to know if $(1)$ admits only a finite number of solutions, or difficult to provide a very good estimation of the size of the sets $N_k$. I'm asking just to get an idea of both questions: what work can be done for **Question 1** and what about the size, or some meaningful inequality for $N_k$ that holds roughly  for **Question 2**, waiting useful answers for this Mathematics Stack Exchange.

Comment: Maybe, this helps : The solutions besides $1$ and $648$ must have a prime factor larger than $3$, at least two prime factors and the largest must have exponent $5$.

Comment: Other solutions are $$51114852$$ and $$26622318750$$ and $$230750426250$$

Comment: Many thanks and very interesting @Peter . I think that this problem is like than a mysterious puzzle (the factors must to fit in a nice way). If you've partial results, feel free to post it as an answer as soon you consider it.

Comment: Hope the below answer helps, note my edit from $q^5$ to $q^6$

Comment: I posted a summary of the $10$ solutions I found but deleted it since I missed something (see below). The list , mathlove posted , should be complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Added** : I've just added a proof of another claim about an upper bound for $N_k$ at the end.

This answer proves the following claim :

**Claim** : $$ N_k=\begin{cases}2 &\text{$\quad $if $\ k=2$}
\\\\4&\text{$\quad$if $\ k=3$}\\\\
16&\text{$\quad$if $\ k=4$}
\end{cases}$$

The only solutions are 
$$\begin{align}k=2& : n=1,2^13^2
\\\\ k=3 & : n=1,2^{2}3^{3},2^13^25^{4},2^13^117^{4}
\\\\ k=4 & : n=1,2^{3}3^{4},2^{2}3^{3}5^5,2^{2}3^{2}17^5,2^{2}3^{1}53^5,
\\&\qquad\quad 2^13^311^{5},2^{1}3^{1}107^5,2^13^15^{5}17^{5},2^13^25^{4}29^{5},
\\&\qquad\quad 2^13^15^{4}89^{5},2^13^{2}5^{3}149^{5},2^13^{1}5^{3}449^{5},2^13^{3}5^{1}1249^{5},
\\&\qquad\quad 2^13^{1}17^{4}101^{5},2^13^{2}17^{3}577^{5},2^13^{1}17^{3}1733^{5}\end{align}$$

*Proof* :

$n=1$ is a solution for $(2)$.

For an odd prime $p$, the numerator of $\frac{p+1}{p}$ is even. This implies that if $n$ is odd larger than $1$, then the equation $(2)$ does not hold. So, $n$ has to be even, and then $n$ has a prime factor $3$.

If $n=2^s3^t$ where $s,t\ge 1$, then $(2)\implies 2^{s+1}3^t=2^k3^k\implies n=2^{k-1}3^{k}$.

If $n=2^s3^t\prod_{j=1}^{d}p_j^{e_j}$ where $p_1\lt p_2\lt\cdots\lt p_d$ are odd primes larger than $3$, and $d,s,t,e_j$ are positive integers. Then, $(2)$ is equivalent to

$$2^s3^t\bigg(\prod_{j=1}^{d}p_j^{e_j}\bigg)\cdot\frac 32\cdot\frac 43\prod_{j=1}^{d}\bigg(1+\frac{1}{p_j}\bigg)=2^k3^k\prod_{j=1}^{d}p_j^k$$
which can be written as
$$\prod_{j=1}^{d}(p_j+1)=2^{k-1-s}3^{k-t}\prod_{j=1}^{d}p_j^{k+1-e_j}$$
where we have to have $s\le k-1, t\le k$ and $e_j\le k+1$.

Since LHS is divisible at least by $2^d$, we have to have $1\le d\le k-1-s\le k-2$ implying $k\ge 3$.

---

$k=2$ :

The only solutions are $n=1,2^13^2$, and so $N_2=2$.

---

$k=3$ :

$n=1,2^{2}3^{3}$ are solutions.

If $n=2^s3^t\prod_{j=1}^{d}p_j^{e_j}$ where $p_1\lt p_2\lt\cdots\lt p_d$ are odd primes larger than $3$, and $d,s,t,e_j$ are positive integers. Then, the equation is equivalent to

$$\prod_{j=1}^{d}(p_j+1)=2^{2-s}3^{3-t}\prod_{j=1}^{d}p_j^{4-e_j}$$
where we have to have $s\le 2, t\le 3$ and $e_j\le 4$.

Since LHS is divisible at least by $2^d$, we have to have $1\le d\le 2-s\le 1$ implying $d=1$ for which we have

$$p_1+1=2^{2-s}3^{3-t}p_1^{4-e_1}$$
Since $4-e_1=0$, we get $p_1=2^{2-s}3^{3-t}-1$ with $s=1$.

- $2^{1}3^{1}-1=5$ is a prime, and $n=2^13^25^{4}$.
- $2^{1}3^{2}-1=17$ is a prime, and $n=2^13^117^{4}$.

Therefore, it follows that $N_3=4$.

---

$k=4$ :

$n=1,2^{3}3^{4}$ are solutions.

If $n=2^s3^t\prod_{j=1}^{d}p_j^{e_j}$ where $p_1\lt p_2\lt\cdots\lt p_d$ are odd primes larger than $3$, and $d,s,t,e_j$ are positive integers. Then, the equation is equivalent to

$$\prod_{j=1}^{d}(p_j+1)=2^{3-s}3^{4-t}\prod_{j=1}^{d}p_j^{5-e_j}$$
where we have to have $s\le 3, t\le 4$ and $e_j\le 5$.

Since LHS is divisible at least by $2^d$, we have to have $1\le d\le 3-s\le 2$.

**Case 1** : $d=1$

$$p_1+1=2^{3-s}3^{4-t}p_1^{5-e_1}$$

Since $5-e_1=0$, we have $p_1=2^{3-s}3^{4-t}-1$.

- $2^{1}3^{1}-1=5$ is a prime, and $n=2^{2}3^{3}5^5$.
- $2^{1}3^{2}-1=17$ is a prime, and $n=2^{2}3^{2}17^5$.
- $2^{1}3^{3}-1=53$ is a prime, and $n=2^{2}3^{1}53^5$.
- $2^{1}3^{4}-1=161$ is not a prime.
- $2^{2}3^{1}-1=11$ is a prime, and $n=2^13^311^{5}$.
- $2^{2}3^{2}-1=35$ is not a prime.
- $2^{2}3^{3}-1=107$ is a prime, and $n=2^{1}3^{1}107^5$
- $2^{2}3^{4}-1=323$ is not a prime.

**Case 2** : $d=2$

Since $s=1$, we have
$$(p_1+1)(p_2+1)=2^{2}3^{4-t}p_1^{5-e_1}p_2^{5-e_2}$$
Now, $5-e_2=0$, and there is a non-negative integer $a$ such that
$$p_1+1=2^13^{a}\qquad\text{and}\qquad p_2+1=2^13^{4-t-a}p_1^{5-e_1}$$

- $p_1=2^13^{1}-1=5$ is a prime and $p_2=2^1 3^{2}5^{0}-1=17$ is a prime, and $n=2^13^15^{5}17^{5}$.
- $p_1=2^13^{1}-1=5$ is a prime and $p_2=2^1 3^{0}5^{1}-1=9$ is not a prime.
- $p_1=2^13^{1}-1=5$ is a prime and $p_2=2^1 3^{1}5^{1}-1=29$ is a prime, and $n=2^13^25^{4}29^{5}$.
- $p_1=2^13^{1}-1=5$ is a prime and $p_2=2^1 3^{2}5^{1}-1=89$ is a prime, and $n=2^13^15^{4}89^{5}$.
- $p_1=2^13^{1}-1=5$ is a prime and $p_2=2^13^{0}5^{2}-1=49$ is not a prime.
- $p_1=2^13^{1}-1=5$ is a prime and $p_2=2^1 3^{1}5^{2}-1=149$ is a prime, and $n=2^13^{2}5^{3}149^{5}$.
- $p_1=2^13^{1}-1=5$ is a prime and $p_2=2^1 3^{2}5^{2}-1=449$ is a prime, and $n=2^13^{1}5^{3}449^{5}$.
- $p_1=2^13^{1}-1=5$ is a prime and $p_2=2^1 3^{0}5^{3}-1$ is not a prime with $3\mid p_2$.
- $p_1=2^13^{1}-1=5$ is a prime and $p_2=2^1 3^{1}5^{3}-1$ is not a prime with $7\mid p_2$.
- $p_1=2^13^{1}-1=5$ is a prime and $p_2=2^1 3^{2}5^{3}-1$ is not a prime with $13\mid p_2$.
- $p_1=2^13^{1}-1=5$ is a prime and $p_2=2^1 3^{0}5^{4}-1=1249$ is a prime, and $n=2^13^{3}5^{1}1249^{5}$.
- $p_1=2^13^{1}-1=5$ is a prime and $p_2=2^1 3^{1}5^{4}-1$ is not a prime with $23\mid p_2$.
- $p_1=2^13^{1}-1=5$ is a prime and $p_2=2^1 3^{2}5^{4}-1$ is not a prime with $7\mid p_2$.
- $p_1=2^13^{2}-1=17$ is a prime and $p_2=2^1 3^{0}17^{1}-1=33$ is not a prime.
- $p_1=2^13^{2}-1=17$ is a prime and $p_2=2^1 3^{1}17^{1}-1=101$ is a prime, and $n=2^13^{1}17^{4}101^{5}$.
- $p_1=2^13^{2}-1=17$ is a prime and $p_2=2^1 3^{0}17^{2}-1=577$ is a prime, and $n=2^13^{2}17^{3}577^{5}$.
- $p_1=2^13^{2}-1=17$ is a prime and $p_2=2^1 3^{1}17^{2}-1=1733$ is a prime, and $n=2^13^{1}17^{3}1733^{5}$.
- $p_1=2^13^{2}-1=17$ is a prime and $p_2=2^1 3^{0}17^{3}-1$ is not a prime with $5\mid p_2$.
- $p_1=2^13^{2}-1=17$ is a prime and $p_2=2^1 3^{1}17^{3}-1$ is not a prime with $7\mid p_2$.
- $p_1=2^13^{2}-1=17$ is a prime and $p_2=2^1 3^{0}17^{4}-1$ is not a prime with $7\mid p_2$.
- $p_1=2^13^{2}-1=17$ is a prime and $p_2=2^1 3^{1}17^{4}-1$ is not a prime with $5\mid p_2$.
- $p_1=2^13^{3}-1=53$ is a prime and $p_2=2^1 3^{0}53^{1}-1$ is not a prime with $5\mid p_2$.
- $p_1=2^13^{3}-1=53$ is a prime and $p_2=2^1 3^{0}53^{2}-1$ is not a prime with $41\mid p_2$.
- $p_1=2^13^{3}-1=53$ is a prime and $p_2=2^1 3^{0}53^{3}-1$ is not a prime with $3\mid p_2$.
- $p_1=2^13^{3}-1=53$ is a prime and $p_2=2^13^{0}53^{4}-1$ is not a prime with $7\mid p_2$.

Therefore, it follows that $N_4=16$.

---

I'm going to prove the following claim about an upper bound for $N_k$.

**Claim 2** : For $k\ge 5$, $$N_k\le 2+\sum_{d=1}^{k-2}(k-2)^d(k-1)k^{d+1}(k+1)^{\frac{d(d+1)}{2}}$$

*Proof* :

We already know that $n=1,n=2^{k-1}3^{k}$ are solutions.

If $n=2^s3^t\prod_{j=1}^{d}p_j^{e_j}$ where $p_1\lt p_2\lt\cdots\lt p_d$ are odd primes larger than $3$, and $d,s,t,e_j$ are positive integers. Then, $(2)$ is equivalent to

$$\prod_{j=1}^{d}(p_j+1)=2^{k-1-s}3^{k-t}\prod_{j=1}^{d}p_j^{k+1-e_j}$$
where we have to have $s\le k-1, t\le k$ and $e_j\le k+1$.

Since LHS is divisible at least by $2^d$, we have to have $1\le d\le k-1-s\le k-2$ implying $k\ge 3$.

We can write
$$\begin{cases}p_1+1&=2^{a_1}3^{b_1}
\\\\ p_2+1&=2^{a_2}3^{b_2}p_1^{c(2,1)}
\\\\ p_3+1&=2^{a_3}3^{b_3}p_1^{c(3,1)}p_2^{c(3,2)}
\\\\\qquad\vdots
\\\\p_d+1&=2^{a_d}3^{b_d}p_1^{c(d,1)}p_2^{c(d,2)}\cdots p_{d-1}^{c(d,d-1)}\end{cases}$$
where $1\le a_j\le k-2,0\le b_j\le k-1$ and $0\le c(j,i)\le k$.

The number of possible $p_1$ is at most $(k-2)k$.

For each $p_1$, the number of possible $p_2$ is at most $(k-2)k(k+1)$.

For each pair $(p_1,p_2)$, the number of possible $p_3$ is at most $(k-2)k(k+1)^2$.

So, we see that the number of possible $(p_1,p_2,\cdots,p_d)$ is at most
$$\prod_{j=1}^{d}(k-2)k(k+1)^{j-1}$$

For each $(p_1,p_2,\cdots,p_d)$, the number of possible $n$ is at most
$$(k-1)k(k+1)^d$$

Therefore, we get, for $k\ge 5$,
$$\begin{align}N_k&\le 2+\sum_{d=1}^{k-2}(k-1)k(k+1)^d\prod_{j=1}^{d}(k-2)k(k+1)^{j-1}
\\\\&=2+\sum_{d=1}^{k-2}(k-2)^d(k-1)k^{d+1}(k+1)^{\frac{d(d+1)}{2}}\end{align}$$

Comment: @Peter : For example, $$n=2^13^1{17}^3{1733}^5=460777037387622037854$$is a solution. It seems that you don't have this number.

Comment: Yes, I saw what I missed. Maybe, you can summarize the solutions and their factorizations. We only have those $16$ solutions, right ? What I missed is, that the smaller prime factor of the form $4k+1$ need not have exponent $1$

Comment: @Peter : Yes, I think the number of the solutions is $16$. I've just summarized the solutions. See the top of the answer.

Comment: Many thanks, perfect. I'm going to read it.

Comment: @user759001 : I've just added a proof of another claim about an upper bound for $N_k$.

Comment: I think that in this ocassion, while I study it, the fair thing is accept your answer since it solves the questions (what work can be done for Question 1 and Question 2). I'm saying it since my thoughts were that these questions should be very difficult but you and @Peter added excellent answers: the fair thing is accept your answer, many thanks again to both for share these results.

Answer (score 2):

Not an immediate method to estimate how many solutions below some $x$ are, but a useful method to classify the possible solutions allowing to determine all solutions upto a very large limit.

Let $S$ be a set of distinct prime numbers. Define $$P:=\prod_{p\in S} (p+1)$$

There is at most one solution $N(S)$ such that the prime factors of $N$ exactly form the set $S$. There is one solution if and only if $P$ has only prime factors belonging to $S$ and there is no prime factor $q$ with $q^6\mid P$. In this case, if we define $$Q:=\prod_{p\in S} p^5$$  the solution is $$N=\frac{Q}{P}$$

Comment: Many thanks, perfect.

Comment: Many thanks again to you and the other user that added such statements. Both, incredible results!